# wordpress access from lan and outside

Tags: wordpress, ip, public, lan, administration

Hello i have a normal wordpress installation in a Raspberry Pi in my lan network(192.168.1.8). The thing is, i just can access to the page and it's administration by the external ip, i can't access it by a lan computer, it redirect me to my ip public address

By changing the Wordpress access (URL) setting in wordpress panel, i can put there the lan ip (192.168.1.8) and then IT WORKS, but now just for LAN COMPUTERS, now CAN'T ACCESS from outside with IP PUBLIC.

PS.I have open ports in router to port 80 redirect to 192.168.1.8(wordpress raspberry)

Answer (score 1):

According to this
https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WP_SITEURL

You can try to put

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

in your wp-config.php